# Light perpendicular to spaceship constant relativistic speed - different points where it hits the wall as seen inside and from outside?

Tags: special-relativity

I googled that question and found this answer:

https://www.quora.com/If-I-had-a-laserpoint-inside-a-very-fast-moving-spaceship-and-I-point-at-the-wall-in-front-of-me-normal-to-the-direction-of-motion-will-the-light-hit-a-bit-lower-due-to-the-speed

Also sometime ago I watched the video on SR paradoxes explanations, where train fits to tunnel and paradox is explained by train not being rigid body:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xrqj88zQZJg

In the quora answer the picture shows that light beam will go diagonally as seen from outside, however person answering claims for insider will see light hit the wall exactly in opposite point.  The video above claims observers should agree on event (e.g. result of train hold in the tunnel). How then observers can agree what point the laser light will point to in the ship?

The ship length will diminish for outside observer, but opposite point on the wall should remain the same as I see it. That laser beam may trigger some other events like Schrodinger cat.

I found only questions regarding simultaneity or exceeding speed of light, however my question is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the laser being inside the spaceship, the answer to the question , *"will the light hit a bit lower due to the speed"*, the correct answer is, "What speed?". The spaceship isn't moving, so a horizontal laser moves across the capsule at a constant height above the floor.

If the laser is 3' above the floor, then so is the spot on the wall (hull?). Of course an external observer for which the s/c is moving upwards at relativistic speed, the height isn't 3', but 3'$/\gamma$, but the source and spot height must be the same distance from the floor.

All that means is that laser isn't aimed horizontally in the external frame. You can consider it a Doppler shift, or a type of stellar aberration, or, if you're a laser expert, you will realize which is a constant phase across the opening of the laser is the s/c frame is a phase ramp to a moving observer, and phase ramps steer coherent beams off the normal of the emitter.

Comment: Then the picture in quora is wrong. right? The beam will go horizontally due to aiming at an angle?

Comment: @Martian2020 The pictures are correct for an external laser considered at rest in relation to the person in the ship. Read JEB's answer carefully.

Comment: @Adrian Howard, I see now, thanx. My karma is not sufficient to upvote your comment.